# Python Threading Audio + Video

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I am working on a head mounted mobile camera based on the Raspberry Pi. It is always recording. On button press the prior two minutes and the following one minute will be saved, remaining recorded files from the buffer will be deleted.

I now want to record not only video but also audio simultaneously via usb soundcard. To do so I need Python threading, I believe.

Sadly, the following code doesn't do anything. Both **while loops** on their one work as intended. But combined in this script as **threading** they won't. The terminal just acknowledges the "sudo python x.py" and responds nothing.

Thanks for every comment!

```
#!/usr/bin/envpython

import subprocess
import datetime

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

from subprocess import call
from datetime import datetime

import os
import sys
import time
import thread

def blink(pin): 
    GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.LOW)
    return

loop=True

def my_callback(channel): #linking the blink to the button press on pin8
        blink(12)
        return

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.IN) #set pin8 as receivable to button input
GPIO.add_event_detect(8, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback) #button and LED are ready

def ongoingvideo():
    while True:
        GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT) #pin12 powers LED
        GPIO.output(12, False) #turn on LED
            ts=datetime.now()
            a= ts.strftime("%H%M%S") #a is time variable
            filename = a #video is called after timestamp
            print "Start recording of a: " + a + (threadname1)
            call (["raspivid -t 60000 -b 15000000 -hf -vf -n -o /home/pi/recordings/vid/buffer/" + filename + ".h264"], shell=True)
            if GPIO.event_detected(8):  
                ts=datetime.now()
                b= ts.strftime("%H%M%S") #b is time variable
                lastfilename = b #video is called after timestamp
                print "Start recording of b: " + b
                call (["raspivid -t 60000 -b 15000000 -hf -vf -n -o /home/pi/recordings/vid/buffer/" + lastfilename + ".h264"], shell=True)
                files = os.listdir("/home/pi/recordings/vid/buffer/")
            files.sort()
            for x in files[-3:]: #"saving" the last 3 files of the endless buffer
                call (["mv /home/pi/recordings/vid/buffer/" + x + " /home/pi/recordings/vid/fullhd30fps"], shell=True)
            call (["rm /home/pi/recordings/vid/buffer/*"], shell=True) #deleting remaining buffer files to free disk space
            call (["sudo fake-hwclock save"], shell=True)

def ongoingaudio():
    while True:
        ts=datetime.now()
            d= ts.strftime("%H%M%S") #d is time variable
            audioname = d #video is called after timestamp
            print "Start recording of d: " + d + (threadname2)
            call (["sudo arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f cd -d 60 /home/pi/recordings/audio/buffer/" + audioname + ".wav"], shell=True)
            if GPIO.event_detected(8):  
                ts=datetime.now()
                e= ts.strftime("%H%M%S") #e is time variable
                lastaudioname = e #video is called after timestamp
                print "Start recording of e: " + e
                call (["sudo arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f cd -d 60 /home/pi/recordings/audio/buffer/" + lastaudioname + ".wav"], shell=True)
                files = os.listdir("/home/pi/recordings/audio/buffer/")
            files.sort()
            for x in files[-3:]: #"saving" the last 3 files of the endless buffer
                call (["mv /home/pi/recordings/audio/buffer/" + x + " /home/pi/recordings/audio/wav"], shell=True)
            call (["rm /home/pi/recordings/audio/buffer/*"], shell=True) #deleting remaining buffer files to free disk space






thread.start_new_thread(ongoingvideo, ())
thread.start_new_thread(ongoingaudio, ())
```

Comment: print doesn't work right on multiple threads.  You might want to try logging instead.  Your code looks like it should run.

Comment: Shortly after this I figured out that I just needed to add a while loop with a pass() at the end to make it run. I now have a better version that I can provide. Just PM me. I will open source it when sound is added.